# Unmarshalling generic types with Json Spray in Akka Http

Tags: akka-http, spray-json

I have routes in Akka Http(Scala) project which are basically the same (CRUD operations) except for entities they operate on

I have my Json formats defined in `JsonSupport` trait like this:

```
trait JsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport {
  import DefaultJsonProtocol._

  implicit val userJsonFormat  = jsonFormat3(User)
}
```

Then I have a route defined which extends this trait, so it works fine if I use a concrete type, but as soon as I have a generic type it fails to compile:

```
def userRoute[T]: Route = 
  pathPrefix("users") {
    post {
      entity(as[T]) { user =>
```

with error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[T]
```

I suspect that it can't find implicit value because the type is too broad.
What type constraints should I give the `T` so it would be able to resolve it?
Is there a way to solve it?

Cheers,
Leonti